# could not cast the value of type 'swift.bool.type' to swift.bool

Tags: swift, types, boolean

I currently have a dictionary:

```
var myfirstcard: [String: Any] = ["thisimagebool": Bool.self]
```

When I add a Bool from an API call to

```
thisimagebool = apicallbool as! Bool
```

and the. try to use `type(of:)` it returns that `thisImageBool` is a `swift.bool.type`.

I do not understand why this Bool ends up to be a `swift.bool.type` instead of a `swift.bool`.

Thank you for helping .

Comment: `Bool.self` is referring to the *metatype* of `Bool`. If `Bool` was a cookie cutter, `Bool()`, `true`, `false`, etc. are all cookies analogous to cookies cut out by that cookie cutter. `Bool.self` refers to the cookie cutter, itself.

Comment: thank you for the quick response changing it to Bool() got rid of swift.bool.type i appreciate your help

Comment: It's better to specifically specify weather you mean `true` or `false`, rather than `Bool()` (which happens to be `false`, but is less obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bool.self` refers to the *type* of Bool, not an instance of an actual Boolean value.

I would declare the dictionary without assigning a value at first, then set the value once you have it from the API.

```
// Initialise dictionary but do not assign keys or values.
// Dictionary could also be [String: Bool] type.
var myFirstCard: [String: Any] = [:]

// Assign value from API
myFirstCard["thisImageBool"] = boolFromAPI // true or false
```

Comment: thanks for showing me a better way to assign a dictionary and that bool.self referred to the type of bool not the value